# Why does Kmail make JPG files larger when I forward them?

Tags: email, conversion, mime-type, kmail

When I forward emails with JPEG attachments inline, the JPEG files size enlarge. Is this normal? Can I turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I forward emails with JPEG attachments inline, the JPEG files size enlarge. Is this normal?

Yes. E-mail standards require that emails consists only of text; JPEG files are binary data. The inline images must first be converted into text, which increases their size. These are converted back into binary JPEG data at the recipient's end.

> Can I turn it off?

No.

---

[The Base64 Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) has more technical information and examples if you are interested in one of the most common ways this conversion takes place -- this one increases sizes by approximately 33%.

Comment: So this will be true for any email client? Funny how I've never noticed it before. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, any email client and almost any attachment: zip, jpg, etc, unless you are attaching a plain text .txt file :)